# Does Java Heap Space Decrease After Program is Run

Tags: java, mysql, heap-memory

I've wrote a Java Program that parses through a mysql database and allocates values. The first time I ran this program on a particular table in the database it ran fine and completed. I have tried to run it more times on different tables and it just keeps running out of heap space. Is there anyway that the heap space is decreasing? It feels as though the program runs for a much shorter time now than it was before. The files are no bigger for this program than they were for the first time it was ran.

Comment: are you starting up the program anew every time? also, posting some code would help

Comment: I have tried restarting the program each time. I've now added the code used

Comment: have you tried closing those 2 statements that you create per call to queryDB() ? also, why do you return the ResultSet if nothing uses it ?

Comment: the returning resultset was a mistake, altered the code earlier and didn't change it. I haven't closed them, I'll try now and see what happens

Comment: youre welcome. while youre taking the effort to improve code performance you might want to consider switching from DOM for your XMl parsing to something faster and thinner like sax or stax ;-)

Comment: You have several empty `catch` blocks. You should not swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you might be having a memory leak in your program. Some of the objects you have loaded are not being GCed which reduces available heap space for new objects.

You might be not having some static references (or) DB connections are not closed, it is hard to guess without seeing some code.

Comment: I've put the methods I think are relevant up. I'm not a great java programmer so theres probably something in the code but I can't work out why or where

Comment: @user1892574: I would start with closing DB resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a memory leak, the amount of free space can decrease.  The maximum heap space is fixed and cannot be changed once the program has started (nor will it change automatically)

I suggest you use VisualVM (or another memory profiler like YourKit) to determine why your application is using as much memory as it is.

A common mistake when using JDBC is not closing off resources.  Unfortunately, unless you do this, the memory they use is not cleaned up automatically.